# TFS build error: Could not find SDK "Bing.Maps.Xaml, Version=1.313.0825.0"

Tags: windows-8, tfs, windows-8.1, bing-maps, tfsbuild

I want to build my windows 8 application on tfs but I have a problem with Bing maps sdk. There are no Bing maps dll that I can easily add it to references. How can I solve the problem? I got this error in tfs build log file.

```
   "C:\Builds\1\...sln" (default target) (1) ->
   "C:\Builds\1\...csproj" (default target) (2) ->
   "C:\Builds\1\...csproj" (default target) (19) ->
   (ResolveSDKReferences target) -> 
     C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1886,5): error MSB3774: Could not find SDK "Bing.Maps.Xaml, Version=1.313.0825.0". [C:\Builds\1\...csproj]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem with this visual studio extension :)

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1f027247-1e01-4ec6-8f5b-70dabb375217

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Bing make SDK to the build server for the build to work properly.

Generally you will need to install everything that you need to install locally to build. Your build server is a consistent mirror of your development environment.